# JS onclick and onkeydown in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to make a custom search box in Sharepoint using HTML and javascript and I cant seem to make it work in Chrome. My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GoSearch()
    {
        var searchString = document.getElementById('txtSearch').value
        window.location.href = '/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx?u=<company web>&k=' + searchString;
    }

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var link = document.getElementById('btnSearch');
    link.addEventListener('click', function() {
        GoSearch();
    });
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var link = document.getElementById('txtSearch');
    link.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
        if(event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnSearch').click();
    });
});
</script>

<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" align="center">
            <input type="text" id="txtSearch" />
            <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I originally had the `onclick` and `onkeydown` directly in the code like this:

```
<input type="button" value="hledat" onclick="GoSearch();" id="searchBtn">
```

but it didnt work and I found while googling, that chrome cant deal with inline functions, so I should add listeners. So i added them and nothing changed. It works in Edge, but in Chrome it just sometimes refreshes the page and sometimes open the page in edit mode (have no idea why) while pressing Enter (seems to work OK while clicking the button manually, only problem is pressing enter).

Am I doing something wrong? I am completely new to JS, so I have no idea, if there is some silly mistake.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: After adding alert into the first listener, it works great, if I delete the altert, it stops working. The code with alert is:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var link = document.getElementById('btnSearch');
    link.addEventListener('click', function() {
        window.alert("here i am")
        GoSearch();
    });
});
```

How is that even possible?

Comment: Do you see any errors in console (hit f12)? Have you tried any debugging steps like adding `window.alert("here i am")` to the event listener to see if it's being triggered? Did you add any alerts or console.log's to the click event listener to ensure that `event` and `event.keyCode` are defined?

Comment: Your code works well with Chrome 48. The inline eventhandler are also well supported.

Comment: Try wrapping up the event in window.onload.

Comment: Ok, this is wierd. I added alerts, to see if it works and with alerts, it executes as intended after I close the alert, but once I delete the `window.alert` it doesnt work again.

Comment: @DipinKumar could you elaborate please? Today is pretty much my first day using JS, so I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad you figured it out. But here is much more elegant way of doing it. Always try to keep your HTML markup neat and tidy.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GoSearch(e){
    var query = document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
  window.location.href = '/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx?u=https://pentahospitals.sharepoint.com&k=' + query;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var queryBox = document.getElementById('txtSearch');
    queryBox.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
        if(e.which === 13) GoSearch();
    }, false);

        var link = document.getElementById('btnSearch');
    link.addEventListener('click',GoSearch, false);
});
</script>

<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" align="center">
            <input type="text" id="txtSearch"/>
            <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Working [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/me_dipinkrishnan/2gnxmn7o/)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. In case anyone search for this in future, here is my solution. All it took was to add return false after functions.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GoSearch()
    {
        var searchString = document.getElementById('txtSearch').value
        window.location.href = '/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx?u=https://pentahospitals.sharepoint.com&k=' + searchString;
    }
</script>

<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" align="center">
            <input type="text" id="txtSearch" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) {document.getElementById('btnSearch').click(); return false;}" />
            <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="GoSearch(); return false;"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```